# Include "space" in filename using Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple batch file splits audio and video of my Unversity lectures. The files are obtained using code from another poster:

```
   @echo off 
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 

set DRIVE=%cd:~0,3%
set MYDIR=%DRIVE%ToDo\ToConvert\

for /F %%x in ('dir /B/D %MYDIR%') do (
    echo %%x
    )
pause
```

The files are labeled:

```
PHY2021 (1).mp4
PHY2021 (2).mp4
PHY2021 (3).mp4
etc
```

The output of the script is:

```
PHY2021
PHY2021
PHY2021
```

The problem appears obvious, but cannot find how to inculde the "space" and what follows in the batch.I have seen ways to replace the "space" with an "underscore" in my search but can anyone tell me if there is a work-around?

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Do you want to (show/process) the filenames so that they still contain the space, or do you want to replace the space with underscores? Batch can also have problems dealing with closed-parentheses. And why `/b/d`? `/b` is sufficient - and overrides `/d`. `/ad` would select directories only or `/a-d` omit directory names, if that's what was required...

Comment: I used the code from another post, i'll ammend it. You are right, it looks like converting the symbols to something else would provide a better fix, such as an underscore, as piping the results to ffmpeg still has the delimiter of the space in the name for some reason.

Comment: Space (also tab, comma, semicolon and equals) is a delimiter in classic batch. Always potential problems dealing with those, and other characters (like `)` `!` `%` `^` `&` `|` `>` `<` ) which have a special meaning in batch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this (use double quotes and no delimiters):

```
@echo off 
setlocal 

set "DRIVE=%cd:~0,3%"
set "MYDIR=%DRIVE%ToDo\ToConvert\"

for /F "delims=" %%x in ('dir /B/D "%MYDIR%"') do (
    echo %%x
)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This worked great. I'll look up the "delims" code to comprehend it better.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I edited my answer to match Endoro's, as I had a mistake there, and in order not to confuse future readers.

There is a default delimiter set of space and tab in `FOR /F`. You need to override it, like this :

```
  @echo off 
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 

set DRIVE=%cd:~0,3%
set MYDIR=%DRIVE%ToDo\ToConvert\

for /F "delims=" %%x in ('dir /B/D %MYDIR%') do (
    echo "%%x"
    )
pause
```

Notice the `delims=` after the `FOR /F`.

From the official `FOR` documentation :

> ```
>     delims=xxx      - specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the
>                       default delimiter set of space and tab.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for explainging the "delims" function, I see what was the problem with out it.

Comment: @kobigurk -- OK, it is batch, but `delims=\r\n` useless code.